# How to remove existing file when uploading new one in codeigniter file uploading?

Tags: codeigniter

I am using codeigniter file uploading class to upload files and images in my local folder.I am using the code below, it's working fine.

```
public function do_upload() {
     $config['upload_path']   = './uploads/';
     $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg|pdf|txt|sql';
     $config['max_size']      = 8048000;
     $config['max_width']     = 1024;
     $config['max_height']    = 768;
     $this->load->library('upload', $config);

     if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('userfile')) {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        $this->load->view('Emp_details_view', $error);
     }

     else {

        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
        $this->load->view('upload_success', $data);
    }
}
```

Now, my question is how to remove previously added file when uploading new one.

Comment: u can use $config['overwrite'] = true ,if a file with the same name as the one you are uploading exists, it will be overwritten.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `unlink()` function to delete your previous image

```
unlink('image-path/image-name');
```

Comment: how to use the image-name dynamically to remove existing image when uploading a new.

Comment: do you know image name or you want to get dynamically ?

Comment: Also tell me only one image exists in the directory or more than one?

Comment: I want to get dynamically. i.e  if i upload a  image with a name new1.png and i uploading another image new2.png ,when i click upload it will remove the previous one(new1.png).

Comment: are you storing image name in the database ?

Comment: No I am not storing image in the database.Just uploading in  my local folder.

Comment: $image = base_url(). "directory-name/image-name"; And then
unlink('directory-name/$image');

Comment: hi,if u dont mind can u you tell how to use the $image = base_url(). "directory-name/image-name"; "image-name" dynamically the above code i mentioned.

Comment: to store your new image?

Comment: No,To delete the old image when uploading new image or file how to use that image or file name dynamically from my code.I posted my code above.could u help me.

Comment: $image = base_url(). "./uploads/"; And then unlink('./uploads/'.$image');

Comment: i am using above lines in my code it display the below error     (Message: unlink(./uploads/http://[::1]/ci/./uploads/): No such file or directory)

Comment: Do this $_FILES['userfile']['name'] = "image.jpg"; in your uploading code after $this->load->library('upload', $config); 

It will set your image name to a specific pattern. Then you can delete your old image easily

Comment: i use those lines.and then i use  unlink('./uploads/image.jpeg');
   $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data()); 
   $this->load->view('upload_success', $data); 
} in my else part .when i run it delete the both files.

Comment: hi are u there?

Comment: if you store all your files in the same directory you have literally no chance of deleting the correct file (previously uploaded for that item), unless there is only 1 image in the directory. either store its path a db table, or make a directory structure where you will have one item per folder (messy) like: /uploads/somecontroller/$id/. Then you still have to iterate over the directory to get the filename of the file that is in that folder as you don't know it. php isn't magic.

Comment: Thanks for ur replay@alex .Now its working fine for me.Tanx a lot

Answer (score 0):

first save your filename in a database table then when unlinking take that value from database and unlink.  here uploads is the foldername .

```
    unlink("uploads/".$val['image']);
```

$val['image'] contains imagename from db.